# Index pandas Series by list of indices in string format

Tags: pandas, indexing

I have a string of indices that looks like:

```
'391:3519, 8602:12512, 17595:21505, 26588:30498, 35581:39491, 44574:48484, 53567:57477, 62560:66470, 71553:75463, 80546:84456, 89539:93449, 98532:102442, 107525:111435, 116518:120428, 125511:129421, 134504:138414, 143497:147407, 152490:156400, 161483:165393, 170476:174386, 179469:183379, 188462:192372, 197455:201365, 206448:210358, 215441:219351, 224434:228344, 233427:237337, 242420:246330, 251413:255323, 260406:264316, 269399:275264'
```

Can anyone think of a way to index a Series (or DataFrame) by these? I've found it surprisingly difficult

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a way to do this:

```
indices = '391:3519, 8602:12512, 17595:21505, 26588:30498, 35581:39491, 44574:48484, 53567:57477, 62560:66470, 71553:75463, 80546:84456, 89539:93449, 98532:102442, 107525:111435, 116518:120428, 125511:129421, 134504:138414, 143497:147407, 152490:156400, 161483:165393, 170476:174386, 179469:183379, 188462:192372, 197455:201365, 206448:210358, 215441:219351, 224434:228344, 233427:237337, 242420:246330, 251413:255323, 260406:264316, 269399:275264'
exec('df2 = df.iloc[np.r_[%s]]' % indices)
df2
```

(here np.r_ builds an index from multiple slices, and exec executes the string)